# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject - when does it actually return 0 value?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, marketing-cloud-connect

The Salesforce AMPscript function UpdateSingleSalesforceObject returns 0 for failure according to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updatesinglesalesforceobject.html). However, all failures of the function we have simulated (for example: invalid SF id, invalid field name etc...) resulted in ERROR 500 and no value has been returned. It seems the only method to get an indication of an error using this function is by using SSJS try{} catch{} functions.

Why the documentation states it can return 0 value when failed - can someone clear this up? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Failure and Error are two different things. As per the document 0 is displayed only in case of Failure but not in case of error.

Example: IF(condition, True, False) When the condition didn't meet the criteria, the result will be False because the record failed the given condition.

Error: The error normally arises in software; it leads to a change in the functionality of the program
Here ERROR 500 means something has gone wrong on the website's server, but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is

Comment: Can you be more specific with regards to this function? Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you please post the code, so we can understand better where the trouble could be

Comment: Hi C. Praveenkumar, this question is not regarding a specific code. Instead I ask for an example of using UpdateSingleSalesforceObject where the return value is 0 (failed). It seems not possible to achieve (even though docs says so). Thanks

Comment: You might achieve that considering if you lack the permission to update something and execute.... I suppose you would get return value as 0. Or if you are trying to Update an Account and pass another objects ID. Technically the code is right or no error but it might return a 0 instead. Just my assumptions.